# how to make Floating widget in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, widget, floating

I am working on website http://weekendr.in/, I have subscribe email widget, I want to make it float with page as it moves up and down.

Answer (score 0):

[**WP FLOAT PLUGIN**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-float/) will do the magic for you.

There are lot of customization options also. Check it:

[image]

Hope this will help you. Cheers!!!